# Passing parameters with array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, variables

I have several instances of slider, and I need to pass the same parameters to every one.

I assume that I need array for that, but since I'm newbie in JS, I'm unsure how to do it properly.

Parameters looks for example like this:

```
spaceBetween: 20,
slidesPerView: 5,
breakpoints: {
  600: {
    slidesPerView: 2
  },
  991: {
    slidesPerView: 3
  },
  1200: {
    slidesPerView: 4
  }
}
```

and slider instance:

```
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
   prevButton: '.b-prev-1',
   nextButton: '.b-next-1',

   //here I need to get the rest of the parameters

});
```

Thank you :)

Comment: look at `$.extend` - it allows you to merge objects together, so you can have `var commonOpts = {spaceBetween: 20 ...}` and then `$.extend({}, commonOpts, swiper1Opts)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can write like below

```js
 var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', [
   prevButton: '.b-prev-1',
   nextButton: '.b-next-1',
   //here I need to get the rest of the parameters
]);
```

Comment: if you to use code snippet certified that works, but, maybe in your answer can be suitable to use code format.

Comment: I have used it because i have faced a problem. Problem i have faced it because of '[' its not formatting properly so i have added in to code snippet

Comment: Independent of the problem, if doesn't works no makes sense to use it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

```
function(arrayP){    
   for(var i = 0; i < arrayP.length; i++){
      alert(arrayP[i]);    //no .value here
   }
}
```

link:-[Passing an array as parameter in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479581/passing-an-array-as-parameter-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$.extend()` :

```
var extraDetails = {
    spaceBetween: 20,
    slidesPerView: 5,
    breakpoints: {
      600: {
        slidesPerView: 2
      },
      991: {
        slidesPerView: 3
      },
      1200: {
        slidesPerView: 4
      }
    }
};

var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', $.extend({ 
        prevButton: '.b-prev-1',
        nextButton: '.b-next-1'
    }, 
    extraDetails
));
```

Answer (score 0):

The most eloquent way of doing this in ES5 is to create a new config object for each slide, but base it off of a common object using [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). ([Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is similar in VanillaJS)

```
var commonConfig = { spaceBetween: 20, slidesPerView: 5, breakPoints: { ... } };

var swiper1 = $.extend(true, {}, commonConfig, {
    prevButton: '.b-prev-1',
    nextButton: '.b-next-1'
});

var swiper2 = $.extend(true, {}, commonConfig, {
    prevButton: '.b-prev-2',
    nextButton: '.b-next-2'
});
```

It'd be cool to see more code -- I imagine you could loop over your DOM elements and create the config on-the-fly for each one. Something like:

```
$('.swiper').each(function(idx, el){
    $(this).swiper({
        spaceBetween: 20,
        slidesPerView: 5,
        breakPoints: { ... },
        prevButton: '.b-prev-'+(idx+1),
        nextButton: '.b-next-'+(idx+1)
    });
});
```